# Input.GetKeyDown doesn't work properly Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have written a simple C# script for player jump(when i press the 'space' button a force is given to player). But it works like about 2 or 3 times for 10 attempts. What's wrong?

```
public float PlayerJump = 100f;
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, PlayerJump * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code seems about right. Maybe try to add a Debug.Log in your code to see if the branch is executed correctly.

Comment: i have added Debug.log. it prints every time i press 'space'. so the problem is with Input.GetKeyDown.

Comment: If it prints every time you press 'space', then it seems to me that the problem is not in Input.GetKeyDown (Debug.Log prints correctly) but in the AddForce function. The physic can be counter inthuitive in unity. The object maybe be falling in the moment you press it, so the force is nearly ignored and so on.

Comment: i have just added ForceMode.velocityChange and it began to work! Now it's time to understand why

Answer (score -1):

Note that multiplying the force by Time.deltaTime does not make sense here. Since it is GetKeyDown, it will only be called for one frame rather than every frame, so this would just make the force depend on the current frame rate the program is running at.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question